# PHP: Decode PDU messages

Tags: php, decode

Does anyone know a written PHP class to decode PDU messages?

I have found one online for JavaScript at http://rednaxela.net/pdu.php , but it is going to take me time to adapt it to PHP.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

```
function DecodePDU($sString = '')
{
    $sString = pack("H*",$sString);
    $sString = mb_convert_encoding($sString,'UTF-8','UCS-2');

    return $sString;
}
```